# How can I compare month and year in sql statment?

Tags: php, mysql

In my database, there's a timestamp column named "date" formated as YYYY-MM-DD

I want to get results older than a specific month and year..

for example:

```
$month = 02;
$year = 2015;
```

And get results older than february,2015.

Dumbly i tried to do something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE MONTH(date)<'$month' AND YEAR(date)<='$year'
```

But.. this query consider only the month number and ignored the year.. And if my data is DECEMBER,2014 it will not be registered since december(12) e > than february(02).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Combine your month and year in code:

```
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("$year-$month-01"));
```

Then compare to that value:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE `date` <= '$date' ;
```

Answer (score 0):

this should be enough if date id of type "date" (YYY-mm-dd)

```
$statement = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE  date<'.$year.$month.'01';
```

if date is "datetime" or "timestamp" try:

```
$statement = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE  date<'.$year.$month.'01000000';
```